# Songs Incorrectly Added to Multiple Google Play Music Albums

Tags: google-chrome, mp3, music, google-drive

Sometimes when I have added one of my ripped CD's tracks to Google Play Music, the tracks incorrectly/annoyingly show up in multiple GPM albums.

For example, I ripped my copy of Hank Williams, Jr.'s "Habits Old and New" to MP3 and added it to GPM...where track 1 appeared in the album "Habits Old and New (Digitally Remastered)" and tracks 2-10 appeared in the album "Habits Old and New (Original Classic Hits - Volume 5)".

I do not see any difference in the ripped MP3 files' metadata that would seem to be responsible for this.  Nor do I see a way to correct the problem in GPM itself - e.g. by editing album or song info, drag & drop merging etc.

How can I avoid or fix this "album fragmentation" when it occurs in GPM?

Comment: Yoy can edit the song/album information in the webapp I believe. its going to be a bit of a pain if you have a lot of music though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @JourneymanGeek's comment, I found that *I had* missed the song-/album-info edit that fixes the problem, which has continued to affect most of my ripped CDs I have added to GPM.

In each pair of fragmented albums, the songs in one of the albums (typically the one with the fewest songs) *show a blank artist*: as soon as I update the artist to match the other album in the pair (e.g. Hank Williams, Jr.), the pair merges - no more fragmentation.

*What's weird* is that I then expected to find corresponding blank artists in some of the source `*.mp3` files' metadata - i.e. that GPM simply reflected the inconsistent metadata for the files I uploaded; but the files' metadata was *consistent and not blank*.

Why artist gets nuked on a subset of songs I upload for most albums, I do not know; but I am glad to at least have a way to end the annoying double vision in My Music that results.

Comment: I had a similar case, source files shows the artist consistent for all files, when copied to mobile, they weren't consistent. It depends on how they were set, some tools sets them differently from other tools. I used mp3tag application, and in the application it showed similar to the mobile, so i edited all the titles to have similar tags with that tool http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the different character encodings used by different apps to store the tags.